# PHP Date and Time and timezone

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

Is there any php function that would convert a date string to its equivalent Asia/Manila time.
I tried setting Asia Manila as my default timezone but no avail.
Please see sample below that needs to be convert to Asia/Manila Time

```
Sun, 12 Jan 2015 08:27:42 +0000,
Mon, 12 Jan 2015 00:14:04 -0500,
Mon, 12 Jan 2015 05:13:34 +0000 (UTC),
Mon, 12 Jan 2015 08:57:47 +0000 (UTC),
Tue, 13 Jan 2015 01:38:04 +0700 (WIT),
Tue, 13 Jan 2015 00:47:31 +0900 (JST),
Mon, 12 Jan 2015 23:27:26 +0000
```

your assistance is highy appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); // Set your default TZ to Asia/Manila

// strtotime() will convert all timezones to your default
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime('Mon, 12 Jan 2015 05:13:34 +0000 (UTC)'));
```

Comment: Thanks For This.. I've already tried this approach however it worked for some timezone.. but some timezone convertion results exceeds my current time time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
$sdt = '2012-05-15 10:50:00';
$stz =  new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$dtz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila');

$dt = new DateTime($sdt, $stz);

$dt->setTimeZone($dtz);

$ddt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Hope this wil help you.

Answer (score 0):

function convert_timezone($from_tz, $to_tz, $time = '2008-08-03 12:35:23') {

```
date_default_timezone_set($from_tz);
$datetime = new DateTime($time);
$time_newTZ = new DateTimeZone($to_tz);
$datetime->setTimezone($time_newTZ);
$newDate = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

return $newDate;
```

}

echo convert_timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', 'America/Los_Angeles');